# Can You Edit a Mixamo Animation In Blender?

Tags: modeling, animation, rigging, unity

Can you edit a Mixamo animation in Blender? If so, are there any tutorials on the internet or YouTube over it? I could not find any.

I am using the low crawl animation where my character crawls straight up and I would like to edit that so I can have two animations of him crawling diagonally to the right and left.

I am using it in Unity 5.2.3 by the way.

Answer (score 2):

The short answer is "yes" it can be done

First you need to convert your animation into something that blender can understand, like FBX or Collada..

My very first search for "import Mixamo to Blender" was an auto-complete suggestion from Google, implying that it's common. And the first 5 hits all seemed pretty useful.